# Basic question about chirp signal

Tags: fft, python, linear-chirp

Suppose I generate chirp signal with the following python code:

```
 t = np.linspace(0, 10, 512)
 f0 = 2
 f1 = 5
 fs = 2*f1
 w = chirp(t, f0=f0, f1=f1, t1=10, method='linear')
 result  = rfft(w)
 phase = np.zeros(257)
 mag = np.zeros(257)
 for binnum in range(len(result)):
   mag[binnum] = abs(result[binnum])
   phase[binnum] = np.arctan2(result[binnum].imag, result[binnum].real)
 plt.plot(fs * np.linspace(0, 0.5, 257),np.unwrap(phase))
 plt.show()
 plt.plot(fs * np.linspace(0, 0.5, 257),mag)
 plt.show()
```

And the phase plot is:[image]

Magnitude plot is:
[image]

But it is very different from what is described [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch11/6.htm).

Well, looking at the phase graph I can see parabola from 0 to 0.8. The magnitude is definitly  not a constant.

What I'm doing wrong or misunderstood?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Sampling frequency is not `2*f1`, even if you say it is.  It's actually 512/10, determined by the linspace parameters.  2. `phase = np.angle(result)` and `mag = np.abs(result)` are easier than your `for` loop.  3.  What did you expect the spectrum of a chirp to look like?

Comment: it should look a little chirpy in the frequency domain.

Comment: This might help, although the code is written for matlab http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/conceptual-question-on-fft-and-chirp-signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand the definition of the chirp in the link you provided (perhaps chirp in frequency domain?), but maybe the following explanation could help.

In general, a linear chirp with a varying frequency given by $$f(t) = \alpha + \beta t$$ is defined by $$ x_1(t) = e^{2\pi j (\alpha t + 0.5\beta t^2)} $$

In that case, the phase of $x_1(t)$, **the signal in time-domain**, is indeed parabolic and the magnitude is constant and equals to 1.
Now, I am not familiar with python, but the `chirp` function in matlab produces a real signal rather than complex one. That is $$ x_2(t) = \sin(2\pi  (\alpha t + 0.5\beta t^2)) $$ In that case, you will get different results. However, you can use the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) (I guess [this is in python)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) which, given $x_1(t)$ will produce $x_2(t)$ using `fft`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused by the frequency-domain response description... It seems that it was time-domain description.